# NMT Using Tenserflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My Code:

```
vocab_size = 10000
total_sentences = 25000
maxlen = 10
epochs = 50
validation_split = 0.05
```

```
split = int(0.95 * total_sentences)

X_train = [encoder_inputs[:split], decoder_inputs[:split]]
y_train = decoder_outputs[:split]

# Test data to evaluate our NMT model using BLEU score
X_test = en_data[:split]
y_test = hi_data[:split]

print(X_train[0].shape, X_train[1].shape, y_train.shape)
```

This is the main part which I've tried tweaking many times but still getting various kinds of errors:

```
d_model = 256

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(english_vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)(inputs)
_,state_h,state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(d_model,activation='relu',return_state=True)(x)

targets = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(hindi_vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)
x = embedding_layer(targets)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(d_model,activation='relu',return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
x,_,_ = decoder_lstm(x, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hindi_vocab_size, activation='softmax')
x = dense1(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets],outputs=x)
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My Model:

```
Model: "model_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_7 (InputLayer)           [(None, None)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_8 (InputLayer)           [(None, None)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_6 (Embedding)        (None, None, 256)    2053120     ['input_7[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 embedding_7 (Embedding)        (None, None, 256)    2405120     ['input_8[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 lstm_6 (LSTM)                  [(None, 256),        525312      ['embedding_6[0][0]']            
                                 (None, 256),                                                     
                                 (None, 256)]                                                     
                                                                                                  
 lstm_7 (LSTM)                  [(None, None, 256),  525312      ['embedding_7[0][0]',            
                                 (None, 256),                     'lstm_6[0][1]',                 
                                 (None, 256)]                     'lstm_6[0][2]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, None, 9395)   2414515     ['lstm_7[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,923,379
Trainable params: 7,923,379
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I get error while trying to fit the above model:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=[save_model_callback, tf.keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN()])
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-b2b3107dbda8> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=[save_model_callback, tf.keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN()])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 10, 9395) are incompatible
```

My Tries:

I tried changing the loss function:

```
d_model = 256

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(english_vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)(inputs)
_,state_h,state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(d_model,activation='relu',return_state=True)(x)

targets = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(hindi_vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)
x = embedding_layer(targets)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(d_model,activation='relu',return_sequences=False, return_state=True)
x,_,_ = decoder_lstm(x, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hindi_vocab_size, activation='softmax')
x = dense1(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets],outputs=x)
model.summary()

loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Error then:

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_11558}} logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,9395] and labels shape [320]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

However all these errors get removed when I set `return_sequences=True` but then after fitting and  predicting I get:

```
Input 0 of layer "lstm_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 256)
```

Comment: What does this return `print(X_train[0].shape, X_train[1].shape, y_train.shape)`?

Comment: It returns: `(23750, 10) (23750, 10) (23750, 10)` @Djinn

Comment: Is there a time sequence in your data?

Comment: No, it actually consists of English text sentences. Should I add more code/data output for reference? @Djinn

Comment: Yes, LSTM requires a time sequence in the input data. A sample of the data might help.